# Sitecore Custom role permissions for experience editor

Tags: sitecore, security-roles

We need to add a custom role which should have edit permissions on the page but should be able to add components\create new content. The user shouldn't be able to publish content or add new pages. He can edit page and add\create relevant components\content on the page. Currently, we've added below roles to the custom role and denied 'create' permission to the role on the entire content tree except for relevant page templates and placeholder settings.

1. Sitecore Designer
2. Sitecore client authoring

But while adding content in experience editor user is getting 'you don't have access to add content' error. What should be the exact set of permissions to be able to add content to pages but not create pages.

Answer (score 1):

By default items are denied access and you need grant the specific access on the items in question. To be able to edit an item a user will need the `Write` permission.

**Resources:**

- [The different Access Rights explained](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/security_and_administration/access_rights/the_access_rights)
- [Assigning Access Rights](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/security_and_administration/access_rights/assign_access_rights_to_a_security_account)